# Convergence in distribution implies more convergence in distribution?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, measure-theory, random-variables

I have the following random variables: $\lambda_i$ which are supported on $\left\{ -1,1\right\} $ and let $$S_n=\sum_{i=1}^{n} \lambda_i$$ and we know:$$\frac{S_{n}}{n}\overset{a.s}{\to}0$$ and $$\frac{S_{n}}{\sqrt{n}}\overset{d}{\to}N\left(0,1\right)$$ and let $\beta>0$ does it imply that: $$\frac{\sum_{i=1}^{n} \lambda_i * i^\beta}{n^{\beta}\sqrt{n}}\overset{d}{\to}N\left(0,C\right)$$ I know it happens for an i.i.d sequence, but I believe that these conditions suffice in this case, any help would be much appreciated

Comment: Have you take a look at Lindeber-Feller theorem and specially the Lindeberg condition?

Comment: they are not independent random variables